# Routing Slip EIP with Camel and Kafka

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

Does Camel routing work with Kafka?

My use case requires that routes/workflows be assembled at runtime, because they are highly dependent on message context, and not fully known at configuration time.  I am thinking about using Camel's Routing Slip pattern which seems to rely on message header (aRoutingSlipHeader) to carry the pipeline end-points.  Kafka does not support JMS format and has very limited support for headers.  Is the RoutingSlip-based route still going to work when combined with Kafka?

Thanks in advance for any wisdom!